# ComboBox PointerExited event fires before I leave it

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a ComboBox, with PointerEntered and PointerExited events as below. The PointerExited event fires even before I leave the ComboBox. It seems a strange behavior. Could it be considered as a bug? Is there any correct event that fires exactly after I leave the ComboBox selecting anything in the ComboBox or without changing anything, whatever the case may be?

```
<ComboBox PointerEntered="Cbo_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Cbo_PointerExited"/>
```

Comment: can you please clarify the behaviour, I guess when u open the combobox and move the pointer to the list of items of the combobox, technically u leave the combobox so the exited event fires, is that wht is happening?  also please explain your usecase as of why you need this behaviour, so that maybe I can suggest an alternate way to achieve that :)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct! That's what I too guessed, when the flyout listbox opens, the combobox's pointerexited event occurs. But, this should not be the intended behavior from the developer's point of view. I want to show some animations, when user enters the Combo and stop it when user exits the combo.

Comment: when the pointer exited event occurs, just check whether combox.isopen ? there must be some property like that, that will help u to know why the pointer exited event occured, I think there are also comboboxopening and opened events. you can track a boolean value between these events and decide when exactly you want your animation logic to execute under some if conditions, I hope you are getting my point here.

Comment: on the other hand combo box can be complicated in ur scenario, consider using "expander" control from windows community toolkit.